# Understood subject of an infinitive

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension

> 1. What a shame (it is) to be wasting our time like that.

It's a sentence in my textbook without context, illustrating the possibility of dropping "it is".

I imagine this sentence is said in a situation where the listener is wasting his own time in some way and the speaker is saying that is a shame. In other words, I read it as:

> 2. What a shame (it is) **for you** to be wasting our time like that.

But my fellow learner argues that the sentence should be understand as:

> 3. What a shame (it is) **for me** to be wasting our time like that.
>    Which expresses the speaker is sorry for what he is doing.

Are both readings potentially possible？

Comment: Logically, since it is our time that is being wasted, you would say _What a shame it is **for us** that our time is being wasted_.

Comment: I’ve voted to close this question as seeking (or likely to elicit) opinions. You might choose to rework it to request more factual answers.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum How is asking whether a sentence can be interpreted a certain way soliciting opinions? Asking more competent speakers whether a particular word could be interpreted in a certain way is acceptable here, so where do you see the difference with a sentence?

Comment: Your imagination is biased. There are any number of situations where that sentence could be uttered and the person spoken to would not be to blame. Let's say two people are applying for a marriage license, and the bureaucratic forms to be filled out are virtually endless: "What a shame, to be wasting our time like that."

Comment: @TimR Are both those readings possible or not?

Comment: @gotube, “Are both readings potentially possible?” simply struck me as leaning subjective, or, as I wrote, likely to elicit subjective responses. Feel free to vote to keep it open, but for me a less opinion-eliciting version could be something like,  “Does either of us have this right?” or maybe, “What are contexts where each of these two readings would be more idiomatic for native speakers?”

Comment: Guys, my advice would be to put question closing low on the list of priorities. But that's just me. We're not army ants guarding a nest. The questions are not existential threats.

Comment: @gotube: "that" can point to any number of culprits.

Comment: Both are at least partly wrong. It could mean 'it is a shame for circumstances (or some event) to lead to us wasting our time like this'. Neither 'you' nor 'me'. The fact that the question does not even consider this make it a poor one, and suitable for closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is ambiguous, and there are several possible interpretations, including (2).

We never use "that" to refer to things we are doing *now* in the *first person*, only "this", so (3) is not a valid interpretation of (1) as written, but it is if we end the original sentence with "*...like this*" instead.

It's also worth noting that *[ "shameful" + "for" + object ]* can either mean "object" did some shameful *action*, or that it is unfortunate for "object" to be in this situation because of something else unmentioned or understood. This opens up many more possible interpretations.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether ***it is*** (or equivalent) is included, the adverbial element ***for us*** is ambiguous in such contexts. It could identify the "agent" (causing the problem), OR the "patient" (*affected* by it). With no explicit  ***for-*** clause, we can only guess who those two parties are. Either of them could be almost anyone *(us, me, you, them, the company,..).*

In principle we can "stack" such elements to identify ***both*** the party affected ***and*** the agent causing the problem...

> *What a shame it is **for the company for us**<sup>1</sup> to be wasting our time and still getting paid!*
> (It's bad for the company that we're wasting our time)

I don't recommend this style to learners, but in many contexts native speakers do things like this without a second thought.

---

<sup>1</sup> Again, *in principle,* either of the ***for-*** clauses could refer to the "agent" ***or*** the "patient". But in practice, *in my specific example*, the first one refers "backwards" ( to the start of the sentence; ***the company*** suffers because of the situation referenced by the entire sentence). And the second ***for-*** clause refers "forwards" (***us / we*** is the subject of the verb ***wasting***). But that's as much pragmatics / logic as it is grammar / syntax.